# new Windows 7 systray - how to show information to users now

Tags: windows-7

new Windows 7 hides systray icons by default.

what is the recommended way to show information to users now?

I need to have a small clickable icon visible to user so user can access my "tool" anytime. Should I use the gadget to show my GUI instead?  Can it communicate with my Delphi app somehow?

Comment: Yay! Now I don't have to constantly hide the damn things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more information it's a little difficult to provide a recommendation.

However, I would imagine that a sufficiently important tool, the user would simply keep minimized. They could then use [Jumplists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460(VS.85).aspx#jump_lists) to access quick functionality.

For example, Live Messenger uses this setup on Win7.

Comment: It looks like Tom's application does not have a window per default, and therefor should not be present at the Jumplist? Also adding Jumplist support would affect backwards compatibility?

Comment: My "minimized" comment was tangential - jump lists work on a pinned taskbar icon even if the app is not running or has no windows.

For backwards compatibility ... perhaps provide a tray icon on those platforms only?

Comment: @Eugene Talagrand, I did not know that, do you have a link about how that works?

Comment: Video: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/yochay/Jump-into-the-Windows-7-Taskbar-Jump-Lists/
The link earlier provides a link to the direct API docs.

Comment: There is no window in my app, its so called "systray application". (you could compare it to Windows Audio Volume Systray app. ) (backward compatibility is important as we still run on Win98etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If your users really like your icon/application they can always choose to not hide your application.

The only difference is that only the user can choose which icon is shown, instead of every  application claiming it's "real estate".

In my opinion this is a good functionality and if I were you I wouldn't change the application, just provide a first run GUI which explains how to make your tray icon visible in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

The entire reason why change was made, was to stop programs like yours. If you need to show information, go ahead and do so. But the notification areas ("systray") is not where shortcuts go. For that, you've got the start menu, desktop and/or the quick launch bar (and please let the user decide).